# Adding inner padding to chart [chart.js v3]

Tags: charts, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm trying to add extra padding to my chart (extra space at the right of the "orange" column):

[image]

But using chart 3.7.0 doesn't seem to work, any idea of how I can achieve this??

`chart.options.scales`:

```
scales: {
    x: {
        afterFit(axis) {
            axis.paddingLeft = 50; //doesn't work
            axis.paddingRight = 50; //doesn't work
        },
    },
},
```

[Full Runnable example](https://jsfiddle.net/0tdqjbfw/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/padding.html) state following

```
let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        layout: {
            padding: {
                right: 50
            }
        }
    }
});
```